# How I can secure some Git Repositories in AIX?

Tags: security, git, access-control-list, aix

I want to secure some git repositories and using only users and groups is not sufficient.

I'm thinking about using ACLs to control the access.

The access to the repositories is local, the users have shell access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest looking at the options provided by `git init --shared=`, but you preempted that by saying "using only users and groups is not sufficient."  So I think your options are:

- ACLs, as suggested by everyone.
- removing local access, and using gitosis to control access via SSH keys.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [AIX acls](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.security/doc/security/access_control_list.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific. How are the users getting to the repositories as it is? Why are users and groups insufficient?

Comment: there are more users in the group than users needing the repository access and I don't have control of how the groups are created or asigned. and the users access the repositories in the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting the comment on the previous, ACLs might indeed be the way to go. It's fairly easy either to grant users access individually, or to give the group access and block certain users. The tutorial [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html) may be useful.